# How to get a custom screen resolution in Xwayland?

Tags: linux, wayland

I have been figuring out to set a custom screen resolution. With custom screen resolution, I mean to say a screen resolution with a resolution that is unsupported by my video card. It is possible in Ubuntu, I had set it to 4K resolution where my laptop just supported 1920x1080. It's possible in Ubuntu because the screen resolutions in Ubuntu are handled by a utility called 'xrandr'. I tried the same codes as I did with the Ubuntu, but they won't work because the screen resolutions here are handled by 'xwayland'.

**Does anyone have any idea to get a custom screen resolution on Fedora with xwayland?**

Answer (score 0):

Either deactivate Wayland:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop

Either this tutorial (did not work for me cause i wanted a higher resolution than provided by the display options)
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/05/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-wayland-xorg/

Comment: Please don’t post a new answer  just to say that another answer didn’t work for you.